# Join Oracle table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I try to join table from Oracle with table from SQL Server using query like this:

```
select *
FROM #Security t
inner JOIN #User_access r
    ON t.[DWSALESRESPONSIBLEUNITOID] = r.[DWSALESRESPONSIBLEUNITOID]
inner JOIN omsp.OMSP.[ICS].[V_D_PERSON]
    ON Login_Name = userwinid
```

omsp is added in Linked Server. This query cause error:

> Invalid use of schema or catalog for OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
>   for linked server "omsp". A four-part name was supplied, but the
>   provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or
>   schema.

I tried to avoid schema or catolog in query with no result.

I have SQL Server 2012 & Oracle 11.

Comment: Have you tried an empty catalog name like `OMSP..ICS.V_D_PERSON`?

Comment: Can you select from the table using OPENQUERY?

Comment: Yes connection works, it gives me results.

Comment: [LinkedServer]..[Schema].[ViewName]
  see the topic on MSDN https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f661b424-971e-4ae4-908d-abe42692d4da/oracle-linked-server-fourpart-name-error